# ¿ Como aplicar descuentos por cantidad a determinados productos segun el rol de usuario?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, porcentaje, hook

Necesito hacer descuentos a determinados roles de usuario de algunos productos,  cuando se compra cierto numero de este producto.

Se debe aplicar el descuento solo al numero de productos que hemos elegido:

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA CON NUEVOS EJEMPLOS**

**- Entre 1 y 9 productos: sin descuento.**
**- El Producto 10 : 5% de descuento.**

**- Entre 11 y 19 productos: sin descuento.**

**- 20  productos: 5% de descuento.**

**- Entre 21 y 29 productos, no se aplica el descuento,**

**- 30 productos, se aplica el 5% de descuento**

**-Osea, unicamente reciben descuento las cantidades que sean múltiplos de 10 (10, 20, 30, 40, 50 )**

**

## EDITO DE NUEVO

**

Necesito hacer diferentes tipos de descuentos a ciertos roles de usuario en algunos de los productos, cuando se compra una cierta cantidad de este producto.
Por ejemplo

- compre 10 (múltiplos de 10) TV, 5% de descuento (5% se aplica solo a cada 10 TV)
- compre 12 (múltiplos de 12) Secadoras, 5% de descuento (5% se implementa solo por cada 12 Secadoras)
- compre 15 (múltiplos de 15) Perforadores, descuento del 8% (8% se aplica solo a cada 15 Perforadores)

El descuento sólo se debe aplicar al número de productos que hayamos elegido en:

Entre 1 y 9 productos: sin descuento.

Producto 10: 5% de descuento en 10 productos.

Entre 11 y 19 productos: 5% de descuento en los primeros 10 productos, sin descuento para el producto 11 a 19

20 productos: 5% de descuento en 20 productos.

Entre 21 y 29 productos: 5% de descuento en los primeros 20 productos, sin descuento para el producto 21 al 29

30 productos: 5% de descuento en 30 productos.

y así sucesivamente siempre en tandas de 10 (10, 20, 30, 40, ..múltiplos de 10)

Por ejemplo: Usuario compra 14 televisores, a un precio de 19,00 €, se aplicará un 5% de descuento a las 10 primeras unidades, las 4 restantes no reciben el descuento.

Tengo alguna otra opción que siempre muestra un texto para el descuento, pero no puedo obtener el descuento de eco para guardar. Quiero decir que cuando subo de 10 productos desaparece el descuento hasta que sumo mas productos hasta 20 productos, que se suma el descuento correspondiente a esa cantidad, pero entre productos de 10 a 20 se hace el 5% de descuento al primero 10 productos desaparecen

El descuento ya obtenido hay que mantenerlo si incrementamos los productos hasta llegar a la siguiente cifra que es múltiplo de 10, a la que le añadiríamos otro 5%. No puedo encontrar la forma correcta. Esta siguiente función consigue mantener el texto en el cuadro, pero cuando tenemos cantidades de productos que están entre 10 y 20, están entre 20 y 30, están entre 30 y 40, etc., el texto se pone a cero, sin guardar el descuento ya obtenido
¿ Pueden ver que esta mal ?

```
function aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad($cart) {
  if (is_admin()) return;
  global $woocommerce;
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_roles = $user->roles;
  $discount_products = array(383); // productos elegibles para descuento
  $discount_role = 'wholesale_customer'; // rol de usuario elegible para descuento
  $subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
  $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
  $discount_percent = 0;
  if (in_array($discount_role, $user_roles) && $count > 0) {
      $discount_eligible_products = array();
      foreach ($cart->cart_contents as $product) {
          if (in_array($product['product_id'], $discount_products)) {
              $discount_eligible_products[] = $product;
          }
      }
      $discount_eligible_product_count = count($discount_eligible_products);
      if ($discount_eligible_product_count > 0) {
          $discount_eligible_product_quantity = 0;
          foreach ($discount_eligible_products as $product) {
              $discount_eligible_product_quantity += $product['quantity'];
          }
          if ($discount_eligible_product_quantity >= 10) {
              if ($discount_eligible_product_quantity % 10 == 0) {
                  $discount_percent = 5;
              } else if ($discount_eligible_product_quantity >= 20 && $discount_eligible_product_quantity <= 29) {
                  $discount_percent = 5;
              }
          } else if ($discount_eligible_product_quantity == 20) {
              $discount_percent = 5;
          }
      }
  }
  if ($discount_percent > 0) {
      $discount_amount = $subtotal * ($discount_percent / 100);
      $cart->add_fee('Descuento por cantidad', -$discount_amount);
  }
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad');
```

Tengo alguna otra opción que siempre muestra un texto para el descuento, pero no consigo que se guarde el descuento echo.
Quiero decir que, cuando pasas de 10 productos por ejemplo, el descuento desaparece hasta que añado más productos hasta llegar   a 20 productos, que se añade el descuento correspondiente a esa cantidad, pero en los productos desde el 10 hasta el 20, desaparece el descuento del 5% echo a los 10 productos

El descuento ya obtenido, debe mantenerse si aumentamos los productos has llegar al próximo numero múltiplo de 10, que añadiríamos otro 5%
No consigo encontrar la forma correcta.
Esta función siguiente, consigue mantener el texto en el checkout, pero cuando tenemos cantidades de productos que estan entre 10 y 20, estan entre 20 y 30, estan entre 30 y 40, etc,  el texto se pone a cero, sin guardar el descuento ya obtenido

Es lo más cerca que hemos estado de conseguir el objetivo

vean que estoy haciendo mal:

```
function aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad($cart)
{
  if (is_admin()) return;
  global $woocommerce;
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_roles = $user->roles;
  $discount_products = array(383, 411, 412); // productos elegibles para descuento
  $discount_role = 'wholesale_customer'; // rol de usuario elegible para descuento
  $subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
  $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
  $discount_percent = 0;
  $eligible_products_count = 0; // variable para contar la cantidad de productos elegibles para descuento
  $discount_applied = 0; // variable para guardar el descuento aplicado

  // recorrer los productos en el carrito para contar la cantidad de productos elegibles
  foreach ($cart->cart_contents as $product) {
    if (in_array($product['product_id'], $discount_products)) {
      $eligible_products_count += $product['quantity'];
    }
  }

  if (in_array($discount_role, $user_roles) && $eligible_products_count > 0) {
    // Cambiar las condiciones para aplicar el descuento solo en múltiplos de 10
    if ($eligible_products_count % 10 == 0) {
      $discount_percent = 5;
    }
  }

  // Guardar el descuento aplicado en una variable
  $discount_applied = $subtotal * ($discount_percent / 100);

  // Añadir el descuento al carrito para mostrarlo siempre, incluso si no se aplica a las cantidades no múltiplos de 10
  $cart->add_fee('Descuento por cantidad', -$discount_applied);

  // Aplicar el descuento si es necesario
  if ($discount_percent > 0) {
    $cart->add_fee('Descuento por cantidad', -$discount_applied);
  }
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad');
```

Answer (score 4):

Siendo que estás usando WooCommerce, si tienes pocos conocimientos de PHP, es muy probable que tengas que usar algún plugin para manejar reglas complejas de descuento y demás. No conozco el mundo de WooCommerce, y parece que los plugin decentes tienen un precio que para un comercio pequeño puede resultar costoso. Por ejemplo [este plugin](https://woocommerce.com/document/product-dynamic-pricing-discounts/) que parece hacer a la perfección lo que pretendes aquí, tiene un coste de US$ 8,25 al mes.

En Wordpress, puede que encuentres algún plugin gratuito que sea bueno, [ver aquí por ejemplo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-discount-rules/).

Desde mi experiencia (sobre todo en entornos como Wordpress) aconsejo depender lo menos posible de los plugin (algunos son inseguros, muchos sitios son hackeados por plugins no actualizados), hacen el sitio web pasado en la medida en que agregas un plugin por cualquier *quítame esta paja*.

Entonces, ¿por qué no tener tu propio diseño, sin plugin, sin no sé cuantos dólares al mes? Eso es posible, y en ese sentido va mi respuesta.

Es demasiado larga, y con un cierto nivel de complejidad. Mi idea es aportar otra vía de solución, que podrás implementar quizá más tarde, cuando tengas algo más de conocimientos de PHP.

## TLDR;

En problemas como el que planteas aquí se puede ver el enorme avance que supone la Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO) para resolver con facilidad situaciones que de otro modo serían harto complicadas.

Mi propuesta sería declarar algunas clases que van a reflejar tus reglas de negocio. Qué vendes, con qué descuentos, según qué condiciones, etc.

Es un diseño básico, con imperfecciones (la idea es probar que no es tan complicado como parece).

Y, si tienes 10 ó 50 plugin, que sepas que esto es lo que hacen, o intentan hacer todos esos plugin, con el agravante de que nunca te enteras de cómo funcionan las cosas en realidad. Los plugin son un peligro también en el orden del conocimiento: son un grave obstáculo al aprendizaje.

Aquí vamos.

Definiremos las siguientes clases, en los comentarios del código explico para qué sirve cada clase.

#### Clase `Product`

```
/*
  Clase para productos (en vez de artículos, porque se suele usar más "Productos")
  Añadiremos una nueva propiedad "category"
  la cual nos ayudará a diferenciar los artículos para la estrategia de descuento. 
  Esto será útil a la hora de saber qué descuentos aplicar.
  "category" será un valor numérico, en y la clase "Category" tendremos la descripción
  y otras propiedades. Lo que estamos haciendo aquí es modelando lo que habría 
  en tu base de datos, donde tendrías una tabla "Product" y una tabla "Category".
  Como ves, en la POO, las clases pueden irse adaptando según las necesidades.
  Imaginemos que haya que aplicar descuentos por marcas del producto,
  pues convendría tener una propiedad "marca" en la clase "Product" 
  y sin duda una clase "Brand" para manejar las marcas de productos.
  */
class Product {
  private $id;
  private $name;
  private $category;  
  private $price;
  
  public function __construct($id,$name,$category,$price) {
      $this->id=$id;
      $this->name=$name;
      $this->category=$category;
      $this->price=$price;
  }
    
  public function getId() {
      return $this->id;
  }   
    
  public function getName() {
      return $this->name;
  }      

  public function getCategory() {
      return $this->category;
  }   
    
  public function getPrice() {
      return $this->price;
  }
}
```

#### Clase `Category`

No tiene demasiada importancia ahora, pero la expongo aquí sobre todo para entender las relaciones entre tablas de la base de datos por ejemplo. Realmente todo está ligado, y los plugin de Wordpress o WooCommerce trabajan con modelos de datos almacenados en una base de datos. Sólo que ellos hacen las cosas por ti.

```
/*
  La nueva clase para categorías de productos.
  Por el momento esta clase no tiene mucha utilidad, 
  para no perdernos en demasiados detalles.
  Pero si quieres mostrar las categorias por su nombre
  convendría usar esta clase, porque en "Producto" sólo pusimos el id de la categoría
  y así debe ser, no poner nunca el nombre de la categoría en las clases derivadas 
*/
class Category {
  private $id;
  private $name;
  
  public function __construct($id,$name) {
      $this->id=$id;
      $this->name=$name;
  }
    
  public function getId() {
      return $this->id;
  }   
    
  public function getName() {
      return $this->name;
  }      
    
}
```

#### Clase `Order`

```
/*
  Clase para órdenes
  Seguimos ampliando el modelo. Tendremos por una parte la clase "Order"
  y por otra parte una nueva clase llamada "OrderDetail" en la cual
  podremos modificar el precio final del artículo según el descuento que aplique
  para más detalles puedes este modelo: 
  https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-queries-for/9780321444431/9780321444431_app02lev1sec1.html
   
*/
    
class Order {
  private $orderId;  
  private $orderDate;
  private $orderDetail;
  
  public function __construct($orderId,$orderDate) {
      $this->orderId=$orderId;
      $this->orderDate=new \DateTime($orderDate);
  }
  public function addOrderDetail(OrderDetail $orderDetail) {
      $this->orderDetail=$orderDetail;
  }   
}
```

#### Clase `OrderDetail`

```
/*
  Clase para Detalles de Ordenes
  Esta clase es la que maneja toda la lógica
  cuando se van agregando productos. 
  Verifica por ejemplo qué nuevos descuentos aplicar, etc.
  Por brevedad, no he puesto por ejemplo un método para 
  quitar productos, en cuyo caso se debe de nuevo verificar
  qué descuentos permanecen vigentes según las nuevas cantidades
  de productos en la canasta, sus categorías, etc. 
*/
class OrderDetail {
  private $allProducts=array();
  private $categoryGroup=array();    
  private $product;
  private $discount;  
    
  public function __construct() {
      $this->allProducts=array();
      $this->discount=new Discount();
  }  

  /*
      Este método agrega uno o más productos a la Orden
      Y verifica qué descuentos aplican según la cantidad,
      las categorías, etc. LLamando a los métodos de la clase Discount
  */
  public function addProduct($p,$qty=1) {
      $idCategory=$p->getCategory();
      if (!in_array($idCategory, array_column($this->categoryGroup, 'idCategory'))){
          $this->categoryGroup[$idCategory]=array('idCategory'=>$idCategory,'counter'=>$qty);
      }else{
          $this->categoryGroup[$idCategory]['counter']+=$qty;
      }
      
      $idProduct=$p->getId();
      if (!in_array($idProduct, array_column($this->allProducts, 'idProduct'))){
          $this->allProducts[$idProduct]=array(
              'idProduct'=>$idProduct,
              'qty'=>$qty, 
              'product'=>$p,
              'discount'=>0,
              'total'=>$p->getPrice()*$qty);
      }else{
          $this->allProducts[$idProduct]['qty']+=$qty;
          $this->allProducts[$idProduct]['total']+=$p->getPrice()*$qty;
      }
      
      #Verifica si aplica el % por cada 12
      #Hace una actualización del discount de ese producto solamente
      $data=$this->discount->checkByTwelve($idCategory,$qty);
      if($data) {
          $this->allProducts[$idProduct]['discount']=$data['discount'];          
      }
      
      #Verifica si aplica el descuento por cantidad
      #Lanza una actualización excluyente
      $data=$this->discount->checkByQuantity($idCategory,$qty,$this->categoryGroup);
      if($data) {
          $this->updateDiscountExclude($data);
      }              
  }

  /*
      Actualización incluyente, es decir, actualiza sólo los productos
      de una determinada categoría, según las reglas de descuento definidas
      en la clase Discount
  */
  public function updateDiscountInclude($data) {
      foreach ($this->allProducts as &$item) {
          $p=$item['product'];
          if (in_array($p->getCategory(),$data['include'])) {
              $item['discount']=$data['discount'];
          }
      }    
  }
    
  /*
      Actualización excluyente, es decir, actualiza los productos
      que no sean de una determinada categoría, según las reglas de descuento 
      definidas en la clase Discount
  */    
  public function updateDiscountExclude($data) {
      foreach ($this->allProducts as &$item) {
          $p=$item['product'];
          if (!in_array($p->getCategory(),$data['exclude'])) {
              $item['discount']=$data['discount'];
          }
      }    
  }      
   
  public function getAllProducts() {
      return $this->allProducts;
  }  
       
  public function getCategoryGroup() {
      return $this->categoryGroup;
  }     
 
  /*
      Este método imprime el estado actual de la orden
  */       

    public function print(){ 
        printf("%s %s %-20s %s %-5s %s %-1s %-5s %5s %s\n",
               'Cant.','','Producto','Total','','Precio final','','% desc','','Categoría');
              
      foreach ($this->allProducts as $item) {
          $p=$item['product'];
          $finalPrice = ($item['discount']>0) ?  $item['total'] * (1 - ($item['discount'] / 100)) : $item['total'];
          printf("%d %5s %-20s %.2f %-5s %.2f %-10s %s %-10s %s\n",
               $item['qty'],'',$p->getName(),$item['total'],'',$finalPrice,'',$item['discount'],'',$p->getCategory());
      } 
    }   
}
```

#### Clase `Discount`

```
/*
    Y vamos a crear una clase para manejar los descuentos
    Tomando lo que has dicho en la pregunta, reflejaremos aquí:
    a. Descuentos de: 5% x cada 10; 10% x cada 20 y de 15% x cada 30
    b. Pero, que esos descuentos no se apliquen a ciertas categorías,
       he puesto aquí como ejemplo las categorías 3,4,5 las cuales entran
       en un descuento particular del 8% por cada 12 artículos comprados
       (no sé si entendí bien tu comentario en ese sentido, es sólo un ejemplo)
    c. Que por cada 12 productos de la(s) categoria(s) N se aplique 8% de descuento,
       he puesto como ejemplo que esta regla se aplique a los productos con categorías 3, 4 y 5
    d. Cualquier otra estrategia la defines en esta clase "Discount"
*/   

class Discount {
  private $orderDetail;
  private $categoryGroup=array();
  private $productGroup=array();    
  private $order;
  private $rulesByQuantity=array(
          'ruleByTen'=>array(
              'exclude'=>array(3,4,5),
              'minCategory'=>2,
               'rules'=>array(
                   array('max'=>10, 'percent'=>5), 
                   array('max'=>20, 'percent'=>10), 
                   array('max'=>30, 'percent'=>15))));
  private $rulesByCategory=array(
           'ruleMax12'=>
              array('max'=>12, 'percent'=>8,'include'=>array(3,4,5)));
    
  public function __construct() {
      $this->sortData();
  }
    
  /*
      Este método verifica si se cumple la regla
      de descuento del 8% por cada 12 productos
      Devuelve null o un array con el descuento a aplicar
      y los ids de categoría a los que se aplicará
      para fines de actualizar el detalle de la orden
  */
  public function checkByTwelve($categoryId, $qty) {      
      $rule=$this->rulesByCategory['ruleMax12'];
      if(in_array($categoryId,$rule['include'])) { 
          if ($qty >= $rule['max']) {
              return array ('discount'=>$rule['percent'], 'include'=>$rule['include']);         
          }
      }
      return null;
  }

  /*
      Este método verifica si se cumple la regla
      de descuento por cantidad de productos comprados
      Devuelve null o un array con el descuento a aplicar
      y los ids de categoría a los que no se aplicará
      para fines de actualizar el detalle de la orden
  */    
  public function checkByQuantity($categoryId, $qty, $categoryGroup) {            
      $ruleByTen=$this->rulesByQuantity['ruleByTen'];
      $data=array('counter'=>0,'qty'=>$qty, 'ids'=>$ruleByTen['exclude'], 'minCategory'=>$ruleByTen['minCategory'],'group'=>$categoryGroup);
      if(!in_array($categoryId,$ruleByTen['exclude'])) {
          foreach ($ruleByTen['rules'] as $rule){
            $data['rules']=$rule;
            if ($this->sumByCategory($data)){
                if ($this->checkCountConstraint($data)){
                    return array ('discount'=>$rule['percent'], 'exclude'=>$ruleByTen['exclude']);
                    break;
                } 
            } 
          }
      } 
      return null;
  }
     
  public function sortData() {
      array_multisort(array_column($this->rulesByQuantity['ruleByTen']['rules'], 'max'), SORT_DESC, $this->rulesByQuantity['ruleByTen']['rules']);
  }

  /*
      Este método verifica la cantidad de productos comprados
      de una categoría dada, para determinar qué descuento aplica
      cuando se deba tener en cuenta el total de productos comprados
      de un rango de categorías únicamente.
      Devuelve un booleano que verifica si el tota de productos comprados
      es mayor o igual a máximo indicado en la regla de descuento
  */    
    
  public function checkCountConstraint($data) {
      array_walk( 
          $data['group'], 
          function( &$value, $key) use ( &$data ){              
              if(!in_array($value['idCategory'],$data['ids'])) {
                  $data['counter']+=$value['counter'];
              }
          }
      );
      $isDiscountable=($data['counter']>=$data['rules']['max']);
      return $isDiscountable;       
  } 
    
  /*
      Este método suma todas las categorías de un posible descuento aplicable.
      Por ejemplo, sirve para verificar que checkByQuantity()
      si la cantidad de productos no son de más de 2 categorías, 
      el descuento no aplique.
      Devuelve un booleano que verifica esa condición.
      Se ha puesto el valor 2 como ejemplo, para hacerlo más dinámico,
      ese valor se puede definir en la regla.en verifica la cantidad de productos comprados
      de una categoría dada, para determinar qué descuento aplica
      cuando se deba tener en cuenta el total de productos comprados
      de un rango de categorías únicamente.
      Devuelve un booleano que verifica si el tota de productos comprados
      es mayor o igual a máximo indicado en la regla de descuento
  */    
    public function sumByCategory($data){
        $sumArray = array();
        foreach ($data['group'] as $k=>$item) {
            if(!isset($sumArray[$item['idCategory']])){
                $sumArray[]=$item['idCategory'];
            }
        }
        return count($sumArray)>$data['minCategory'];
    }

}
```

#### Prueba del código

Dadas las clases anteriores, vamos ahora a probar el código.

```
/*
   Datos de prueba que representan
   los productos que vendes
*/
$testData = array(
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>"Televisor",        'category'=>1,'price'=>19.10),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>"Radio",            'category'=>1,'price'=>10.99),
    array('id'=>3, 'name'=>"Lavadora",         'category'=>3,'price'=>40.99),    
    array('id'=>4, 'name'=>"Abanico",          'category'=>4,'price'=>12.99),    
    array('id'=>5, 'name'=>"Frigorífico",      'category'=>2,'price'=>70.10),    
    array('id'=>6, 'name'=>"Licuadora",        'category'=>5,'price'=>6.50),    
    array('id'=>7, 'name'=>"A. Acondic.",      'category'=>4,'price'=>20.99),    
    array('id'=>8, 'name'=>"Tostadora",        'category'=>5,'price'=>5.99),    
    array('id'=>9, 'name'=>"Componente",       'category'=>1,'price'=>43.99),    
    array('id'=>10,'name'=>"Aspirador",        'category'=>3,'price'=>14.10),    
    array('id'=>11,'name'=>"Congelador",       'category'=>2,'price'=>80.00),    

);

/*
    Las reglas de descuento definidas son las siguientes:
      a. Por cantidad incremental
        - Si se compran 5+  productos que NO sean de las categorías 3,4, 5: 5%  descuento
        - Si se compran 20+ productos que NO sean de las categorías 3,4, 5: 10% descuento
        - Si se compran 30+ productos que NO sean de las categorías 3,4, 5: 15% descuento
        - PERO la suma 5, 20 ó 30 tiene que ser de productos de más de dos categorías
        
      b. Por cada 12 productos
        - Si se compran más de 12 productos que sean de las categorías 3,4,5 un 8% descuento
      
      Creamos un set de datos a mano, para verificar si el código funciona
*/        

$oneOrder=new Order(1,"20230424");

$orderDetail=new OrderDetail($oneOrder);
addTestData($testData[3],13,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[2],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[3],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[4],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[5],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[6],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[7],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[9],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[0],21,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[2],4,$orderDetail);
addTestData($testData[5],14,$orderDetail);

$oneOrder->addOrderDetail($orderDetail);
$orderDetail->print();

/*
    Esta función es sólo de prueba,
    para meter datos y probar el funcionamiento de las clases
*/
function addTestData($arr,$qty,$orderDetail){
    $oneProduct=new Product($arr['id'],$arr['name'],$arr['category'],$arr['price']);
    $orderDetail->addProduct($oneProduct,$qty);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Cant.  Producto        Total       Precio final   % desc   Categoría
----------------------------------------------------------------------
17      Abanico        220.83       203.16           8        4
8       Lavadora       327.92       327.92           0        3
4       Frigorífico    280.40       252.36          10        2
18      Licuadora      117.00       107.64           8        5
4       A. Acondic.     83.96        83.96           0        4
4       Tostadora       23.96        23.96           0        5
4       Aspirador       56.40        56.40           0        3
21      Televisor      401.10       360.99          10        1
```

Si analizas los datos, se aplicará un descuento del `8%` al `Abanico` y la `Licuadora` porque cumplen con las reglas que hemos definido en la clase `Discount`. Igualmente, se aplica un `10%` al `Frigorífico`, y al `Televisor`, porque también cumplen con las reglas definidas en `Discount` para esos productos.

Pues bien, con esto, tu problema queda resuelto... Sin plugins que te cuesten tantos dólares al mes. Realmente, lo que hacen esos plugin es algo parecido a las pocas líneas de código expresadas más arribas. Que sí, que habrá otras reglas, otras complejidades, pero, para eso serás programador, para resolver problemas complejos que no lo son tanto, porque la POO nos ayuda precisamente a resolver con sencillez problemas complejos.

Y el resultado no es sólo que te ahorras unos dólares al mes, sino que escribes un código ligero, que no depende de plugin, y totalmente ensamblado, incorporando elementos como tu base de datos.

#### Pero, ¿cómo incorporo esto a mi contexto?

Con este diseño, sólo tienes que preocuparte de dos cosas:

- Crear las instancias de cada clase
- Y llenarlas de objetos

Los datos de prueba que he puesto aquí a mano, son lo mismo que un escenario donde un usuario selecciona productos y los va metiendo en un carrito y el estado de la orden se va actualizando, desde la lógica que se desarrollar en el método `addProduct()` de la clase `OrderDetail`. No hay más misterio. Como dije más arriba, con esta respuesta intento mostrar lo que pasa en realidad. Los plugin son una cortina de humo, que te impiden ver el horizonte muchas veces y si puedes, no dependas de ellos. Puedes programar tu propio código.

En fin, te invito a tirar de la POO para resolver estas cosas. Una vez diseñas la clases sólo tienes que empezar a usarlas en tu contexto, ensamblando cada cosa adecuadamente.

Las clases aquí mostradas son muy básicas, las puedes ampliar, adaptar, mejorar, actualizar cuando surjan nuevos requerimientos.

Espero que esto se acerque a una *respuesta canónica* y si tienes alguna duda, pregunta en comentarios al pie de la respuesta.

---

#### Demo

Aquí te dejo una <kbd>[**`DEMO EN LÍNEA`**](https://rextester.com/XIQ38697)</kbd>, por si quieres probar otras posibilidades de este enfoque.

---

Comment: Increíble @A.Cedano. Me costara digerir todo esto aunque lo explicas muy bien, aun estoy aprendiendo y lo veo tan fácil como usted. Déjeme que haga alguna prueba, ya que como bien dice en su explicación, tengo que implementar otros 6 tipos diferentes de descuentos a otros productos ( por ejemplo: compra 12 lavadoras y recibe el 8% de descuento) tambien tenemos que tener en cuenta que si hay dos productos diferentes que tienen el mismo tipo de descuento (TV y Aspiradores reciben descuento de 5% cada 10 uds.) No podemos permitir que se cree un descuento si añadimos al carro 5 TV y 5 Aspiradores.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @A.Cedano, lamento el tiempo que usted a dedicado a crear este increíble ejemplo, pero no logro entender como aplicarlo a mi proyecto. Estoy a la espera que un amigo con más habilidades que yo pueda revisarlo y decirme, porque personalmente no se por donde cogerlo

Comment: @unity-student he actualizado la respuesta dando más amplitud al código, exponiendo por ejemplo una clase `Discount` para manejar ciertas reglas de descuento. Mi idea con esta respuesta es mostrar una solución en código puro, orientado a  objetos, sin dependencia de plugin y demás. Aunque no de inmediato, podría ser un enfoque interesante en un futuro no muy lejano, cuando estés un poco más familiriazado con PHP.

Comment: Es increíble. Por supuesto, recibirá la recompensa, la dedicación que ha puesto a esto es de admirar. Sigo sin entender como utilizar esto, lo guardare para estudiar y tratar de crear el sistema que usted me propone. Aun asi, debe decir que el descuento no es por cantidad, y que se aumente con el aumento de productos. Edite la pregunta y espero haber explicado bien lo que estoy buscando. Son varios tipos de descuento diferente, pero la cantidad debe ser a un múltiplo del numero de productos que estipulemos en cada tipo de descuento. El comentario al inicio de la Clase Discount, es erroneo

Comment: @unity-student Como dije en el comentario, no entendí la regla que aplicabas para los descuentos, sea cual sea, lo puedes adaptar. La idea es entender que en la POO diseñas las clases para responder a necesidades concretas sean cuales fueren.

Comment: Gracias, necesitare tiempo para entenderlo, pero la idea me gusta. Edite la pregunta y muestro exactamente lo que estamos buscando. Empece a estudiar de nuevo php y espero entender tus ideas en breve, por el momento, me supera. Muchas gracias. La respuesta no me vale aún, pero te concedo la recompensa por tu afán por hacerme entender el funcionamiento y el modo de crearlo

Comment: @unity-student en la clase `Discount`, el array que se llama `$rulesByQuantity` tiene un sub-array cuya clave es `ruleByTen` en el cual he definido una regla de descuentos tratando de adivinar la lógica que estabas siguiendo para los descuentos. Si no es correcta, como dices, y lo que se debe es aplicar un tanto por ciento de descuento a todos los productos en un rango de `N`, sería cuestión de modificar el código. De hecho, si sólo es eso, el código sería más sencillo, porque lo que he implementado es una lógica más compleja, que excluye ciertas categorías y que verifica que no haya ...

Comment: ... demasiados productos del mismo tipo entre lo que se compra (creí entender eso en un comentario en el que decías que si de los 10 eran por ejemplo 5 de un mismo tipo y 5 todos de un mismo tipo, el descuento no aplicaba). Sea como sea, es una regla de descuento y tú puedes escribir código para cada regla de descuento que necesites. Como ya dije, esa es la gran ventaja de la POO: cualquier requerimiento nuevo lo defines tú mismo y punto, sin tener que depender de código de terceros.

Answer (score 2):

En tu codigo (a continuación); mi sugerencia:

> Siendo tú código

```
  if (in_array($discount_role, $user_roles) && $eligible_products_count > 0) {
    // Cambiar las condiciones para aplicar el descuento solo en múltiplos de 10
    if ($eligible_products_count % 10 == 0) {
      $discount_percent = 5;
    }
  }
```

Aquí estas usando `if ($eligible_products_count % 10 == 0)`; recuerda que 11 o 14 (por decir unos números) no da como residuo 0; es aquí donde esta el detalle. Lo que debes verificar es cuantas veces es divisible el `$eligible_products_count` con (en tu caso) el 10. Lo que necesitas es el cociente el cual claro debe ser un numero entero para ello te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
  $cociente = (($eligible_products_count - ($eligible_products_count % 10)) / 10);
  if (in_array($discount_role, $user_roles) && $eligible_products_count > 0) {
    // Cambiar las condiciones para aplicar el descuento solo en múltiplos de 10
    if ($cociente>0) {
      $discount_percent = 5;
    }
  }
```

El `$cociente` te indica a cuando productos acorde a su precio debes aplicar el porcentaje de descuento; es decir si seleccionan 14; te dara 1; por tanto seria multiplicar ese 1 por 10 veces el precio del producto y aplicar el % que corresponda; si fuesen 21; te dará igual y misma operación.

De lo que leí de tu código; abajo te coloco un comentario, por que el descuento tendrías que hacer cuando es la *N* cantidad (quiero pensar) del mismo producto... si es el caso, tendrás que realizar los ajustes respectivos a tu código.

Comentario:

> Su estructura del código abajo; me da la percepción que no está contabilizando por producto; en tu ejemplo colocas que si ingresa 10 televisores tiene derecho a descuento; pero tu codigo daria descuento si por ejemplo pongo (por decir) 5 televisores (y asumiendo radios tienen descuento) 5 radios; en total serian 10 unidades de productos con descuento.

```
// recorrer los productos en el carrito para contar la cantidad de productos elegibles
  foreach ($cart->cart_contents as $product) {
    if (in_array($product['product_id'], $discount_products)) {
      $eligible_products_count += $product['quantity'];
    }
  }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para efectos prácticos no profundizare mucho, será sugerencia de flujo y lo adaptes a tu código.
Para agilidad de explicación partiré *tomando* de lo que tiene el carrito dos elementos estos serán **Producto** y **Cantidad** *(lo que "nos interesa")*; de su segundo código de `aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad` sería dentro del mismo realizar lo siguiente (pasos; no código):

```
function aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad($cart)
{
    /* lo anterior o necesario */
    // Tu código
    /*
    // recorrer los productos en el carrito para contar la cantidad de productos elegibles
    foreach ($cart->cart_contents as $product) {
       if (in_array($product['product_id'], $discount_products)) {
          $eligible_products_count += $product['quantity'];
       }
    }
    */

    /*
    Realiza una estructura que te permita agrupar los productos elegidos y la cantidad(ver nota 1).
    Lo anterior con tal de obtener un dato donde este el producto con el total de unidades solicitadas.
    Ejemplo
    */
    $productos=new array();
    foreach ($cart->cart_contents as $product) {
       /* Obtener de cada producto el total de unidades solicitadas */
       if (!in_array('product_id', producto)) {
          $productos[$product['product_id']] = new array();
          $productos[$product['product_id']]['totalUnidades'] =0; // Unidades en total
          $productos[$product['product_id']]['montoTotal'] =0;
          $productos[$product['product_id']]['precioUnidad'] =0;
          $productos[$product['product_id']]['montoDescuento'] =0;
          $productos[$product['product_id']]['porcentajeDescuento'] =0; // este debes obtenerlo y asignarlo o si es fijo ponerlo
          $productos[$product['product_id']]['ameritaDescuento'] =in_array($product['product_id'], $discount_products);
       }
       $productos[$product['product_id']]['totalUnidades'] += $product['quantity'];
    }

    /* Realizar proceso para obtener el precio por unidad de tu catálogo o donde corresponda */

    if (in_array($discount_role, $user_roles)) {
       // Cambiar las condiciones para aplicar el descuento solo en múltiplos de 10
           foreach ($productos as $producto) {
              // Cálculo del monto total (sin descuentos)
              $producto['montoTotal'] =$producto['totalUnidades'] * $producto['precioUnidad'];

              if ($producto['ameritaDescuento']) {
                 // Cálculo del descuento
                 $cociente = (($producto['totalUnidades'] - ($producto['totalUnidades'] % 10)) / 10); // si cada producto tiene descuento por unidades diferentes considera agregar igual cuantas unidades generan el descuento y reemplaza el 10
                 $producto['montoDescuento']= ($producto['precioUnidad']*10) * ($producto['porcentajeDescuento']/100) * $cociente;
              }

           }
    }

    /* si nada me falta y te es ilustrativo; luego de la interacción anterior tendrás en cada elemento el monto a descontarle */

} // aplicar_descuento_por_cantidad
```

> **(1)**.- Asumiendo que el usuario puede ("exagerando") 10 veces el televisor (o cualquier otro producto) con cantidad igual a 1. Realizar la sumatoria de lo que el mismo producto.

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación. Claro, debemos tener en cuenta que cada producto debe ser independiente. Y es un detalle que no había pensado, porque tendré varios productos que llevaran el mismo descuento por cantidad, (por ejemplo cada 10 productos el 5% de descuento). Y seria un problema que si el descuento es llegando a 10 productos, no podemos permitir hacer el descuento cuando se compren 5 televisores y a 5 radios. ¿ Como puedo corregir esto ? Esta tengo el problema que cuando añado productos y estan entre 10 y 20, el descuento desaparece, aparece de nuevo, al llegar a 20, y no debe ser asi